# Is it possible to retrieve event information from Fabric Api?

Tags: google-fabric

I need to show live information of specific (custom) event from Fabric api on the website. I'm not quite sure if that's possible, since I couldn't find something in docs or stackoverflow. Would really appreciate for advice

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Right now it's not possible to get API access to the realtime event stream in Fabric. Our tools are migrating into Firebase where we have realtime BigQuery access to Analytics data and 24 hour latent data for Crashlytics.